# How I can change MailEnable's hourly sending limit?

Tags: windows-server-2008, mta

It seems MailEnable limits users with 100 email per hour as default. I want to change that limit but couldn't find any option for this.

I digged manuals and configuration files but no luck.

Do you have any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems there is no way to do that in standard version.

Answer (score 1):

I believe this is doable in Mailenable Standard (v6).

Open the Mailenable interface and then expand

> Servers > [your server] > Connectors
>
> Right-click SMTP, then select Properties > Security tab

Here you can set a per-hour send limit.